# Comparing two scipy.sparse matrices in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I work on a program that deals with large networks and therefore I have to use sparse matrices (preferrably `scipy.sparse.csr`). Now I would like to write a function that takes two sparse boolean matrices A and B and returns B without those entries that are set in A. Here is a pseudo-code example.

```
def f(A, B):
    return B and (not A)
```

How can this be done with scipy.sparse matrices?

Comment: This pseudocode would not work with numpy boolean matrices, at it would complain that you are using boolean operations on matrices. Following would work with normal matrices: `return B & ~A`.

Comment: Even if either worked, you would not really want to do `not A` or `~A`, as the result would not be sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to implement your function:

```
def f(a, b):
    return b - b.multiply(a)
```

`b.multiply(a)` is effectively an element-wise `and` operation.

Here's an example. `a` and `b` are sparse matrices:

```
In [134]: b.A
Out[134]: array([[False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [135]: a.A
Out[135]: array([[False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [136]: f(a,b).A
Out[136]: array([[False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot your quick help

Comment: Please can you explain what the capital lette 'A' is?

Comment: @Willower, I never noticed how hard it is to find documentation for `.A`!  It is an attribute that returns the same thing as the `toarray()` method.  That is, `b.A` is the same as `b.toarray()`.  The implementation in the source code of `.A` (and a few other attributes) is at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/0a9e93e23453cce2f5e861bf6dc4168d788fdb51/scipy/sparse/base.py#L675